# Using stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a weather database in MySQL. My database get data from arduino, but sometimes the arduino have some error and send error value in my database. I want to make a stored procedure to reject this error. I want using if then in stored procedure. Example if temperature < 20 then MySQL reject this data. Is it possible? Help me please with the coding

this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `cuaca_maritim`.`weather_data` (
 `idweather` INT(10) NOT NULL,
 `temperature` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
 `HUMID` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
 `AIRPRESSURE` DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
 `WIND` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`idweather`))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
 COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just want a view:

```
create view good_weather_data as
    select wd.*
    from weather_data
    where temperature >= 20;
```

I don't really see why a stored procedure would be necessary.  You *might* want a trigger that rejects invalid data values when they are loaded.

Comment: No I don't want a view, I want my database can reject data, so that data will not saved in mydatabase. Can you help me

Comment: Then you want a trigger.  Start with the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html.

Comment: I try using trigger before, but after I using it, the arduino can not send data to mysql

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following stored procedure to do your work.

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_weather_data (IN temp INT) 
proc_main: BEGIN
IF (temp > 20) THEN
   INSERT INTO weather_data(temperature) VALUES (temp);
END IF;
END proc_main #
DELIMITER;
```

Here I have only consider the temp you can do the same for other parameters also

Comment: VALUES(temp) , what does it mean ?

Comment: you are inserting temp parameter value which is taken in the stored procedure.

Comment: The stored procedure doesn't work,  I try to input value < 20 in temperature, but my database still  save the data, it doesn't reject the data. Why?

Comment: please send me the total code. That is this procedure calling part also.

Comment: USE `cuaca_maritim`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `suhu`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `cuaca_maritim`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `suhu`(IN suhu_udara decimal)
BEGIN
IF (suhu_udara > 20) THEN
   INSERT INTO data_cuaca(suhu_udara) VALUES (suhu_udara);
END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;

Comment: Actualy I want if value in suhu_udara <20 then MySQL will reject the data

Comment: ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'proc_main #

Comment: What is your mysql server version?

Comment: after I using the update answer, suddenly my stored procedure doesn't exist , version 5.6.22

Comment: I guess, version is ok, Because I am also using the same version. Refresh your object browser , Right click on stored procedure and click refresh

Comment: I try but nothing happened when I call the stored procedure

Comment: Is your stored procedure correctly created now? , Then please send me the stored procedure calling code.

Comment: call cuaca_maritim.suhu(0); this is the calling code

Comment: Lets try this way, change your parameter datatype to int. Then call the procedure like this. "call suhu(2);"